# Влияние отрицательного margin-top на порядок элементов по оси z

Tags: html, css, z-index

Имеется два `div`'а, у второго есть css-свойство `margin-top: -50px`. Но получается так, что первый `div` располагается выше второго (выше по оси `z`). Почему так?

```css
#a {
  font-size: 70px;
}

#b {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Казалось бы, статически позиционированные элементы должны располагаться по оси `z` в порядке их появления в html

Comment: Если сделаешь букве A красный цвет, то увидишь, что видно текст поверх. Если сделаешь фон тексту, то увидишь, что все же второй див перекрывает первый.

Comment: Буквы просто сливаются из-за одинакового цвета, и кажется, что A выше из-за иллюзии

Comment: @mJeevas, да, точно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вам так кажется, на самом деле блок `#b` выше блока `#a`. Вот пример:

```css
#a {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#b {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```